# How to make generic object to accept two different class models

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I want to have 2 very similar classes that will have some common behavior, but different properties, so I need to make these two classes `Invoice` and `CreditNote` to be under "one generic object" in this case called `model`

I was thinking to implement a inteface which will be having input object type like:

```
public interface IInvoice<T>
{
    T InvoiceType { get; set; }
}
```

But Im not quite sure if this is the way for this.
Ultimately, I would like instancing these classes from interface: `IInvoice = new Invoice();`

Here is an example:

```
//380-invoice
if(Convert.ToInt32(invoiceType) == InvoiceTypeCodeEnumDto.Invoice.Id)
{
    Invoice model = new Invoice();
    model.RequestId = request.CorrelationId;
    model.SendToCir = "Auto";
}

//383-creditNote
if (Convert.ToInt32(invoiceType) == InvoiceTypeCodeEnumDto.CreditNote.Id)
{
    CreditNote model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CreditNote>(request.Content)!;
    model.RequestId = request.CorrelationId;
    model.SendToCir = "Auto";
}

model.Name = "foo"; // not accesible
```

Comment: Are you sure you want a generic base class? From your description, it sounds like you would be fine with an interface

Comment: yes, I mean I started implementing the interface, but Im not sure is this a right path.
I need just to instate it class A or class B depending of the some bool value in the code, and rest of the mapping should be the same (they will have duplicated properties)

Comment: I would go with the interface, sounds like a more logical approach. Not sure you'll gain anything with a generic base class

Comment: can you just put an example? becuse this interface should be generic one right? and how would look like an implementation for that?

Comment: Looks like AceGambit has done it for you 

Comment: Is this more of what you are thinking of? => https://dotnetfiddle.net/nxgHDB

Answer (score 1):

Interface seems like the right answer for what you're trying to accomplish. Read up some more on interfaces and polymorphism to fully understand their usage.

Interfaces are correct for you if...

You want any class working with your `IInvoice` objects to be completely blind to whether the object it's handling an `Invoice` or `CreditNote` save for the brief moment when your objects are created.

It looks like you're 90% of the way there, the one thing it seems you're missing is that interfaces are not "instantiated", classes are.  so you can have the following method:

```
public IInvoice CreateInvoice(Request request, int invoiceType)
{
  //380-invoice
  if(Convert.ToInt32(invoiceType) == InvoiceTypeCodeEnumDto.Invoice.Id)
  {
    Invoice model = new Invoice();
    model.RequestId = request.CorrelationId;
    model.SendToCir = "Auto";
    return model;
  }

  //383-creditNote
  if (Convert.ToInt32(invoiceType) == InvoiceTypeCodeEnumDto.CreditNote.Id)
  {
    CreditNote model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CreditNote>  (request.Content)!;
    model.RequestId = request.CorrelationId;
    model.SendToCir = "Auto";
    return model;
  }

  throw new NotImplementedException($"Unexpected invoice type {invoiceType}");
}
```

and then anywhere in your code you can use

```
IInvoice myInvoice = CreateInvoice(request, invType);
```

the only members of `myInvoice` you'll be able to access are the ones defined on the interface `IInvoice`.  If you want to access the `Name` property, you'll need to either add it to the `IInvoice` interface and implement it on both `Invoice` and `CreditNote` or you can down-cast your `myInvoice` object into a concrete type which has the `Name` property exposed.  I don't recommend this approach since the whole point of polymorphism is to remove concrete understanding of the underlying implementation.

---

**Edit:** after thinking about your comment I think I understand what you want, let me know if the following makes sense.

You can make just the one model like so:

```
public class InvoiceMode
{
  public long RequestId{get;set;}
  public string SendToCir {get;set;}
  public string Name{get;set;}
  ... etc
}
```

and then in your code you can have the following:

```
public InvoiceModel CreateInvoice(Request request, int invoiceType)
{
  InvoiceModel model;

  //380-invoice
  if(Convert.ToInt32(invoiceType) == InvoiceTypeCodeEnumDto.Invoice.Id)
  {
    model = new Invoice();
  }

  //383-creditNote
  else if (Convert.ToInt32(invoiceType) == InvoiceTypeCodeEnumDto.CreditNote.Id)
  {
    model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CreditNote>  (request.Content)!;
  }

  // Unknown invoice type -- throw error
  else 
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException($"Unexpected invoice type {invoiceType}");
  }
  
  model.RequestId = request.CorrelationId;
  model.SendToCir = "Auto";
  return model;
}
```

Comment: not quite an answer, because, in your case I will have duplicated logic code. for example `model.RequestId` twice, Im trying to avoid that. To have one logic for both classes, and to be "blind" which class should come

Comment: Basically I want to have one common `var model` above if statements, to be able to use it independently of deserialzied class

Comment: I think I misunderstood your ask then, apologies.  Is there something stopping you from creating just a single `InvoiceModel` class and instantiating it both with a constructor AND with `JsonConvert`?

Comment: Also,  you can split that in two: if you want different properties accessible during initialization than during usage, make a builder, that uses one interface to set properties a,b and c and have it return another interface that exposes property d.

Comment: @Stefan0309, I edited to add a different solution that might align better with what you're looking for.  Is that more like what you wanted?

Comment: I think I need template method pattern https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/template-method-design-pattern/